# Custom field is not saving to customer_entity in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento

I have created field in customer_entity table and added in registration form. I am able to getdata in getParams(). I am posting my observer code and events.xml file. I face no error and getting log in debug.log. Just field is not saving in the table.

**db_schema.xml**

```
<table name="customer_entity">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="my_code" nullable="true" length="20" comment="My Code" />
</table>
```

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="savecustom_custom_register" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Accountcreate"  />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Accountcreate.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class Accountcreate implements ObserverInterface
{
    /* METHOD-1 
    protected $customerRepository;

    
    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->_logger->info("Observer CustomerRegisterObserver Loaded !");
        $accountController = $observer->getAccountController();
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $request = $accountController->getRequest();
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('my_code', 'abcdef');
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
        $this->_logger->info("Observer CustomerRegisterObserver SAVE DONE !");
    }*/
    
   // METHOD-2
    protected $_customerFactory;
    protected $_customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }


    public function execute(Observer  $observer)
    {
        $this->_logger->info("Observer CustomerRegisterObserver Loaded !");
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $customerData = $event->getCustomer();
        $customer = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customerData->getId());
        $customer->setData('my_code', 'abcdef');
        $customer->save();
        
    }
}
```

Field is created properly just value is not saving to table.